# Yarn build is not working in docker, typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, yarnpkg

When I build project myself using `yarn build` it works properly, but when I build  docker container it gives me typescript error. A week before everything was working fine.

```
No overload matches this call.
#12 97.88   Overload 1 of 2, '(props: InfiniteScrollProps | Readonly<InfiniteScrollProps>): InfiniteScroll', gave the following error.
#12 97.88     Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/app/node_modules/@types/styled-components/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
#12 97.88   Overload 2 of 2, '(props: InfiniteScrollProps, context: any): InfiniteScroll', gave the following error.
#12 97.88     Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/app/node_modules/@types/styled-components/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.  TS2769
```

My dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
RUN yarn
COPY . ./

ARG REACT_APP_BASE_URL

ENV REACT_APP_BASE_URL $REACT_APP_BASE_URL

RUN CI=false yarn run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: You're not copying the `yarn.lock` file into your image so it's possible your host and container build environments are getting different package versions.  Does it help to include `yarn.lock` in the same line you `COPY package.json`?

Comment: Thank you, you were right, it worked after including yarn.lock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as @David Maze already answered it is probably due to a mismatch of your packages. We had a similar issue with NPM, and we had to solve it by copying the lock file as well.

```
COPY package.json package-lock.json .npmrc ./
```

Besides that make sure you are using the same node version locally and on the CI server/build image, some packages can be different between the versions (node 12 - 16, we had some issues with devs locally running 10 or 12 and the CI system was on 16).